# Connection between group of daemons and main process - mkfifo

Tags: c, linux, connection, daemons, mkfifo

I was trying to connect daemons (group of daemons without a leader) with main process as in title, the problem is that i have to send statement from each daemon(which are supporting SIGUSR1 signal) to main process, but i don' t even know how to do that, in my code i used mkfifo, but it's not working at all..
here is the main process source:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   pid_t pid;
   int i;
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   char c, message[255];
   if(argc!=2){
      printf("please insert one parametr\n");
      return -1;
   }

   int fd = open("pipe", O_RDONLY);
   if (fd == -1) {
      perror("Failed open fifo to read");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   for( i = 0; i < n; i++) {        
      pid=fork();
      if (pid==0){
         printf("daemon created..\n");
      }
      else{
         execl("daemons", "daemons", argv[1], NULL);
         while(1){
            sleep(2);
            read(fd, message, c);           
            printf("P received: %s\n", message);
            close(fd);
            //read(fd[0], message, sizeof(message));
         }      
      }
   } 
   return 0;   
}
```

and here is some source code in which i create daemons:

```
int fd = open("pipe", O_WRONLY);
if (fd < 0){
    perror("cannot open fifo: ");   
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if ( getppid() == 1 )
    return 0;
/*  Creating daemon     */
pid[n] = fork();
if (pid[n] < 0)     
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  

if (pid[n] > 0)    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
/*  Setting leader of session */
sid = setsid();  
if (sid < 0){  
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
}  
/*  fork one more time to make children 
to have an opportunity to destroy
session leader  */

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++){
    pid[i] = fork();

    if(pid[i] < 0){
        printf("filed to fork...\n");    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }        
    if(pid[i]==0){

        while(1){                   
            sleep(2);
            printf("Demon[%d]: My ID in pipe.%d\n", i+1, getpid()); 
            signal(SIGUSR1, sigHandler);    
            write(fd, "Hi\n", strlen("Hi\n"));
            close(fd);
        }
    }       

chdir(".");

close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);

file = fopen("log_file.txt", "w+");

fclose(file);

umask(027);
}
```

at least i' m not sure about that i am creating daemons in good way..
And where i should put signal, which can be later executed?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to send a signal (`SIGUSR1`) to a process, or to send a stream of data through a pipe?

Comment: to send stream of data from daemon to main process

Comment: By the way, aren't you supposed to call `execl` in the *child* of your "main" process? Right now you do it in the parent (or if `fork` failed), and the `exec` family of functions *never returns*.

Comment: Also, if you move the `execl` call to the child, so the loop can run, then you will have *undefined behavior* as you use the uninitialized variable `c` as the number of bytes to read. Uninitialized local non-static variables have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Lastly about that `SIGUSR1` thing, you set a signal handler to handle `SIGUSR1` (which you only should do once) but you actually never send it to the program. And you *really* need to check for errors, especially when reading from a pipe. Oh, and in the "main" process you will print out an unterminated string, again leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ok, i' ve just done it, but now i have other problem, it' s strange because when i call execl it is not working in child, but when i execute daemon program, the main process achives some messages from daemons

Comment: i have declared sigHandler above the main function, something like that:
   void sigHandler(int signum){
    if (signum == SIGUSR1){
  printf("signal catched!");
 }}

Comment: Yes, but nowhere (not in the code you show) do you actually *send* the `SIGUSR1` signal. You send signals with the [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call. And you haven't really explained why you need it, and what it has to do with the pipe?

Comment: oh, so firstly, daemon have to send statement, next statements are send within executing SIGUSR1 signal

Comment: If you want my opinion, I think you are trying to do to much at one time, there are lots of code you show that doesn't really make any sense. Instead I suggest you take a few steps back, and start over, and start *simple*. Like just having your "main" program fork and execute another program, and where the other program just prints a "hello world" type of string. Then add one little bit at a time, one by one, until the system does what you want it to. That will make it easier to learn, but also easier to debug and find out and fix problems.

Comment: so i would start from that, i have main process which is executing second process - daemons - with some number of arguments, next, i create daemons which are in one group and have no leader, but i don' t know how to do something like each daemon send simple statement

Comment: All problems I can see above -- signaling and FIFO ordering -- could be solved easily switching to an Unix domain socket instead. Then, no signals would be needed, nor would there be any of the other issues FIFOs often exhibit.